# Change the URL of the current Themeable Browser window

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Seems like this should be fairly simple, but I can't get it to work. I just want the resourcesPressed() event to change to a different URL, in the same browser. My code:

```
  openBrowser() {
    const options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
      toolbar: {
        height: 65,
        color: '#008ba6ff'
      },
      title: {
        color: '#ffffffff',
        showPageTitle: false,
      },
      closeButton: {
        image: 'home',
        align: 'left',
        event: 'closePressed'
      },
      customButtons: [
        {
          image: 'resources',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'resourcesPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'cbt',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'cbtPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'chat',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'homechatPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'contact',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'contectPressed'
        }, 
        ],
        backButtonCanClose: true
    };

    const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.themeableBrowser.create('https://homeweb.ca/dashboard', '_blank', options);

    browser.on('closePressed').subscribe(data => {
      browser.close();
    });
    browser.on('resourcesPressed').subscribe(data => {
      browser.open('https://google.ca/', '_self', options)
    });
  }
```

The current code for resourcesPressed doesn't work (Property 'open' does not exist on type 'ThemeableBrowserObject'). What should this be?

Answer (score 1):

Solved using executeScript:

```
openBrowser(pageToOpen) {
    const options: ThemeableBrowserOptions = {
      toolbar: {
        height: 65,
        color: '#008ba6ff'
      },
      title: {
        color: '#ffffffff',
        showPageTitle: false,
      },
      closeButton: {
        image: 'home',
        align: 'left',
        event: 'closePressed'
      },
      customButtons: [
        {
          image: 'resources',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'resourcesPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'cbt',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'cbtPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'chat',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'homechatPressed'
        }, {
          image: 'contact',
          align: 'right',
          event: 'contectPressed'
        }, 
      ],
      backButtonCanClose: true
    };

    const browser: ThemeableBrowserObject = this.themeableBrowser.create(pageToOpen, '_blank', options);

    browser.on('closePressed').subscribe(data => {
      browser.close();
    });
    browser.on('cbtPressed').subscribe(data => {
      browser.executeScript({
        code: "window.location.href ='www.example1.com';"
      });
    });
    browser.on('resourcesPressed').subscribe(data => {
      browser.executeScript({
        code: "window.location.href ='www.example2.com';"
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using this plugin: https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

I'd do this:

```
const browser = cordova.ThemeableBrowser;
```

I can't see what ThemeableBrowserObject is for, and .create() doesn't exist.

Provided it works like InAppBrowser that it's a fork of, each call to open() opens a new browser view.

Did you add cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser to the project?

Comment: I am using that plugin, yes. It's working great in every other way, I just cant get my custom button to change the URL in the same window. Seems like it should be something simple, but nothing is working.